# Sending audio stream usign asyncio

Tags: asynchronous, python-asyncio, pyaudio, python-socketio

I'm trying to stream microphone data to an asynchronous server. The client code is below. My first attempt was without using await asyncio.sleep(0), but the code was getting blocked. I imagine it was getting blocked because the process never finished, not allowing the event loop to consume the messages. Is this statement correct? When I added await asyncio.sleep(0), the event loop could be consumed.

Well, I imagine there's a more correct way to do this. What would it be? Would it be by spawning a thread in the client? Can someone provide me with a code snippet?

```
@sio.event
async def speechData(data):
    print("message received with ", data)


async def main():
    audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
    CHANNELS = 1
    RATE = 16000
    CHUNK = int(RATE / 10)

    await sio.connect("http://localhost:9000")
    await sio.emit(
        "startGoogleCloudStream",
        {
            "audio": {
                "encoding": "LINEAR16",
                "sampleRateHertz": 16000,
                "languageCode": "pt-BR",
            },
            "interimResults": True,
        },
    )

    stream = audio.open(
        format=FORMAT,
        channels=CHANNELS,
        rate=RATE,
        input=True,
        frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
    )
    while True:
        data = stream.read(CHUNK)
        await sio.emit("binaryAudioData", data)
        await asyncio.sleep(0)

    # this shoud be here?
    await sio.wait()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: My understanding is that PyAudio is not compatible with asyncio, so a better way to do this would be to use the sync Socket.IO client. Or else, you should use an audio library that is compatible with asyncio (uses async/await), but I'm not really sure if there is one.